# GSuite displaying "via" next to name after DNS change

Tags: email, g-suite, gmail, dmarc

After changing over to Cloudflare GSuite has been adding "via" next to the names of incoming emails. After a quick Google search I found this:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en

However my DMARC reads:

```
v=DMARC1; p=none;
```

This is driving me insane and causing a lot of time loss, how can I remedy this problem?

Answer (score 0):

check G Suite configuration with this tool
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/

Ensure that DKIM and SPF records are properly added to Cloudflare